# How can I send data from a PHP file to an Android handset that is not connected to my computer?

Tags: android

How can I send data from a PHP file to an Android handset that is not physically connected to my computer?

I only know the number and IMEI number.

I have a string generated by the php file in the browser (whose value is 1011, 1000, 1111 for example).  I want to send this string to particular person who has android sets with them.

Comment: It would probably be best to put the php file on a web server that is publicly available. Your question is not very clear, maybe you could provide more information on what you're trying to do.

Comment: exactly i want to send a string to a android set and on the basis of that string a form will be drawn inside android phone..kind tell me how i can send the string through webserver..

Answer (score 2):

There are so many different ways and different tutorials, here's one or just google android httpClient.

[How-to: Android as a RESTful Client](http://senior.ceng.metu.edu.tr/2009/praeda/2009/01/11/a-simple-restful-client-at-android/)